# impyla - as_pandas - empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, impyla

I have a simple `impyla` code, and I would like to create a `pandas` `dataFrame` from my cursor. My code is running but my `dataframe` is always  an empty `dataframe`. 
If I run my query directly on `impala`, the result is not empty. This is how my code looks like:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.util import as_pandas


conn = connect(host='impala_server', port=21051,
               user='user' , password='pass',
               use_ssl=True,
               auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE")

results = cursor.fetchall()

df = as_pandas(cursor)

print(df.head())
```

Help me please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove:

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

from your code. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
'results = cursor.fetchall()  ' delete this line and it will be ok.

    from impala.dbapi import connect
    from impala.util import as_pandas
    
    conn = connect(host='****.com', port=****, database='****')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from table limit 10')
    df = as_pandas(cursor)
    df.head()
```

I run the code above, and it run well.